# Geoserver Style Error

Tags: geoserver, sld

I was applying a style and there was no validation error. But when I am about to press submit I am getting the following error

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/styles/bangalore_poi_others.sld (Permission denied)

I am using geoserver 2.1.2 and apache tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing chmod of the /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/geoserver/data/styles/. Geoserver probably cannot access files inside this folder because of its access restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure the GeoServer process has RW access to the GeoServer data dir.

BTW, since you are, make sure you move the data directory OUTSIDE the tomcat webapps  directory as a redeploy (e.g. GeoServer update/upgrade) would swipe out your data directory otherwise.

Check this link:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-setting.html

Simone.